# How to add a gap in a line html

Tags: html

I am in HTML, and I'm making a header for my website. I have a website title, followed by some links to various pages. By default, they are right next to each other, and I want them to be apart. I've tried the simple option of just adding multiple spaces, but it puts it as just 1 space.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: If you expect any sensible answers, you need to post a **complete** `code snippet` (HTML, CSS & JavaScript including CDN links) that allows *replicating your issue exactly*. Otherwise, any answers would be based on guesswork and you want to avoid that. [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: non breaking spaces, but you should learn CSS to avoid ugly stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are separate links then you should put padding on the link or some margin

```
 `<a href="#" style="padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px">Link text</a>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your code here so that you will get more help at SO.

Is this what you are trying? See if this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }

li {
    display: inline;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#link1">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link2">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link3">link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link4">link4</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code and I test it. if you want to change the spacing between elements just change the padding of the li element

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    float: left;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px; // this is the space between elements you can add whatever you like
}
```

```
<h1>The website title</h1>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```